# Python Range function 100 - 0, on the same line

Tags: python, function, range

so one of my assignments is to make a program in python to countdown 100 - 0 in increments of 10, i wrote the code but cannot figure out how to make it work on the same line instead of it using multiple lines to countdown. here is what i have so far.

```
def main():

    print(" I will print 100 down to 0 in incriments of 10 ")


    for num in range(100, -10, -10):
        print(num) 

main()
```

Comment: Google "python print on same line"

Comment: Maybe use a string that gets updated in your loop

Comment: Are you talking overwriting or one long line?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join),

```
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in range(100, -10, -10)])) # 100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 0
```

---

Or use [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) with the argument `end=' '`, as mentioned by **@PadraicCunningham**, but notice that there is one more space at the end, as pointed by **@user2357112**.

```
from __future__ import print_function   # for Python2

# Usage
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

# Demo
for num in range(100, -10, -10):
        print(num, end=' ') 

print('END')

# Output, notice that one more space at the end
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 0 END
```

Comment: `end=" "` would do the same job

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: But it'd print a spurious space at the end of the line, which matters sometimes.

Comment: @user2357112, true, I was going to suggest unpacking but spark already edited, I think the erroneous space at the end may not be a deal breaker here though.

Comment: @user2357112, PadraicCunningham. Many thanks. I just included your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `end=" "` parameter to `print`

```
for num in range(100, -10, -10):
    print(num, end=" ")
```

This will override the default newline character `'\n'`